# Tie Image to Repeater link Button

Tags: image, hyperlink, repeater, linkbutton

I have a link button getting populated with my repeater template here,

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand" runat="server">

  <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnlinkgroups"
 CommandName="cmd" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Eval("ItemTypeDescription")   %>'
 CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemTypeID")  %>'/><br />                                         
  </ItemTemplate>                                                       
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Currently the Text (ItemTypeDesc) is the link buttons name. How can I add a png image which is in the same directory instead of text. The images aren't stored in the DB so I need a way to link each image to the correct link button

Thanks

Comment: Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: IMHO, you are probably not getting answers because it is unclear exactly what you are asking. Do you want the button to be an image? Is the name of the image file contained in "ItemTypeDescription"?